# AngularJS(1) view and directve not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am making a small application in angular to study, but the directive and the view are not being rendered, I already investigated my code, but I did not find anything, code can be seen below:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="rdi_music">

<head>
<base href="/">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Carregando CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-overloads.css">

<!--Carregando os scripts-->
<!-- App core -->
<script src="js/core/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- My Modules -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/index-controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/musicas-controller.js"></script>

<!-- My Directives -->
<script src="js/directives/header.js"></script>

<title>Music</title>
</head>

<body>

<header-menu></header-menu>

<div class="container">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
angular.module('rdi_music', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'musicasController', 
'header'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/musicas',{
    templateUrl: 'views/musicas/index.html',
    controller: 'musicasController'
});
});
```

**index-controller.js**

```
angular.module('rdi_music', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('indexController',function($scope){
$scope.isNavCollapsed = true;
$scope.isCollapsed = true;
$scope.isCollapsedHorizontal = true;
});
```

**musicas-controller.js**

```
angular.module('rdi_music', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('musicasController', function($scope){

});
```

**header.js**

```
angular.module('header', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.directive('headerMenu', function(){
var ddo = {
    restrict: "AE",
    templateUrl: "views/directives/header.html"
};

return ddo;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once the module injected to the `angular.module` no need to inject them again. Just get the reference only.

remove the 'musicasController' from the module injector. Controllers don't need to inject to the modules

```
angular.module('rdi_music', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 
'header'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/musicas',{
    templateUrl: 'views/musicas/index.html',
    controller: 'musicasController'
});
});
```

index-controller.js

```
angular.module('rdi_music')
.controller('indexController',function($scope){
$scope.isNavCollapsed = true;
$scope.isCollapsed = true;
$scope.isCollapsedHorizontal = true;
});
```

musicas-controller.js

```
angular.module('rdi_music')
.controller('musicasController', function($scope){

});
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/HXy49Px4cz5qFScminbg?p=preview)